# hyper-ledger can not find enrollAdmin.js file

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I followed "Writing Your First Application" tutorial. when I get to this section "Enrolling the Admin User"[enter link description here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html#enrolling-the-admin-user)
it asks me to launch this command `node enrollAdmin.js`.

But I check out my current directory, this file just doesn't exist. and I try to google it on the internet, search it on my computer, I still can not find it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bf1r.png)
How you guys work out this? Do you have corresponding files?
Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to follow http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/write_first_app.html which is our stable documentation link.

Put another way, you should use the stable rather than latest version of the docs.

The doc link you used points to our latest code but has not updated to point to a preview release yet.

Comment: correct, apologies for the confusion. this should be straightened out now with the correct links being shared for a given release.

Comment: for convenience, [link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/fabcar) `enrollmentAdmin.js` is here.